# Hidden highlighting error

Tags: errors, highlighting

I have no idea why the following MWE should have errors. I would really appreciate it if you could help.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,soul}

\begin{document}

\hl{used the Monte Carlo simulation to explore different staffing policies and minimize infections among SMs on non–COVID-19 wards. They reported that longer nursing shifts and less co-rotation of SMs (no more frequently than every three days) may lead to fewer infections.} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your text includes a non-ascii dash, the original soul package can not cope use `soulutf8` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,soulutf8}

\begin{document}

\hl{used the Monte Carlo simulation to explore different staffing policies
    and minimize infections among SMs on non–COVID-19 wards. They reported 
    that longer nursing shifts and less co-rotation of SMs (no more frequently
    than every three days) may lead to fewer infections.} 
\end{document}
```

That said, it is far more conventional to use a hyphen `-` rather than an en-dash `–` after `non` so is this dash really intended here?